# phpoffice phpword сохранение файла

Tags: php, phpword

Каким образом корректно отдавать файлы сформированные php word?

Использую такой вариант:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.doc"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

Файл нормально открывает только Word. Open Office, Libre Office ругаются на файл. При этом если сохранять файл как в доках `echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);` то готовый файл открывается любым офисным пакетом.

Чяднт?

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось очень просто. Для формата Word 2007 нужно ставить расширение .**docx** иначе libre, open не смогут с ним работать.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.docx"');
```